# Efficiently using shaders

Tags: opengl

I am trying to combine two old openGL widgets into a new one.
These two old widgets have different shaders.

For efficiency consideration, shall I do:

1) Combine the different shaders into a new one and use uniform value to switch between them.

2) Or I just use different programs which have different shaders and switch bewteen programs?

Comment: I guess this depends on what these programs do. If these two programs are for different data and only inputs they share is vertex positions, there is no reason to not write two programs. If these two programs have at least same uniforms, it can be done, but i have not noticed any considerable slow-down when switching programs, so unless these two programs are just different algorithm over same data, it's better to split it.

Comment: Firstly, batch as much of the same stuff together as you can. This will improve both 1 and 2. You might want to look into [subroutines](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Subroutine) too. If you're only drawing a few things then it'll be fast either way, so choose the easy-to-implement option.